# Selenium - Not able to import package 'org.openqa.selenium.environment'

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm not able to import the package 'import org.openqa.selenium.environment;' It says it cannot be resolved when trying to import in eclipse.

Selenium version - 3.141.59 
Eclipse - Neon 
Java - 1.7

But i can be able to find this in the selenium source code. 
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/tree/master/java/client/test/org/openqa/selenium/environment

Not sure, whether i'm missing something here.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But i can be able to find this in the selenium source code.
>   https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/tree/master/java/client/test/org/openqa/selenium/environment

Notice that that URL contains **/test/** .  In other words, that class belongs to the unit tests rather than the production code, which is why you can't find it in the production jars.

Answer (score 0):

Not all files in GitHub are exposed in the [API](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/). There is no `environment` package available.